# Page fits width in browser Responsive Design View, but not on phone

Tags: css, iphone, mobile, responsive

I just have a simple page with no media queries that looks great in the Responsive Design Mode but not on my phone.

In the Responsive Design Mode the table fits completely. (Safari, Chrome, and Firefox)

However, on my 375px test phone (iPhone 6s), the last column (21px image) doesn't fit, and must be horizontally scrolled into view. (Safari, Chrome, and Firefox)

I deleted the phone cache and made sure the page zoom in Safari preferences is 100%.

The viewport is set properly:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Is this fixable?  I hope the problem isn't with the Responsive Design Editors, because if so, they're not very useful if they don't match actual phones.

```css
.dt { border-collapse:collapse; font:11px Arial; }

.dt caption {background:black; color:orange;}

.dt th {font-size:12px; background: gainsboro; border:1px solid silver; padding:4px;}

.dt caption+tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child {background:white; font-weight:normal; font-size:11px; text-align:left}

.dt td {border:1px solid silver; padding:3px; text-align:center}

.dt div {width:21px; height:12px; background:lightgreen}
```

```html
          <table class="dt">
            <caption>Title</caption>
              <tr>
                <th>Brand</th>
                <th id=AAcapacity>CapacityXF</th>
                <th>XF?</th>
                <th>1+2 star<br>
                  reviews</th>
                <th># reviews</th>
                <th>Price per 8</th>
                <th>Pic
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Raspberry</td>
                <td class="lg">2800</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>7%</td>
                <td>385</td>
                <td>$13.99</td>
                <td><div></div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Blueberry</td>
                <td class="lg">2700</td>
                <td>XTC</td>
                <td>10%</td>
                <td>585</td>
                <td>$15.99</td>
                <td><div></div></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  When I got my phone long ago, I'd set it to Settings > Display & Brightness > Display Zoom > View > Zoomed, then forgot about that.  At the time, I thought that that setting just drew everything bigger, but what it actually does is to turn the iPhone 6s from a 375px-wide display to a 320px-wide display.  I just turned off the Zoom and then I got a 375px-wide display, and now the table fits properly.